# Calculators are bad at Arithmetic

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

Consider the following fraction:

> 17/30

Punch this into a calculator and you'll get the following answer:

> 0.566666666666666666666666666667

However, I disagree. I say the answer is most certainly "0.6"

I could be rounding (0.56 can round to 0.6), but I'm not.

I could be saying that "0.6" is a limit of some kind, like in [0.999999999... = 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDtFBSjNmm0), but, for the purposes of this puzzle at least, I'm not. I'm am asserting that this is true equivalence in the mathematical sense of the word, in the same way that 2 + 2 = 4.

How could this be?

---

Hint:

> All these numbers appear to be in base 10. But why be so closed minded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> You're computing in base eleven.
>
> In case anyone's wondering, here's how I found the base: The given equation, $17/30=0.6$, if it's written in base $b$, says that $(b+7)/3b=6/b$. And then we solve that for $b$.

Comment: Excellent. Did you need the hint?

Comment: I guessed it might be a different base before seeing the hint, but looked at the hint before figuring out which base.

Comment: Beat me too it, good eye!

Comment: I like the equation. Didn't think of that.